# What is the correct docstring documentation for self variable passed to another class

Tags: python

If I have two classes `A` and `B` where the object of the first class passes its `self` to the second class like below. What do I say is the type of that `self` variable when I perform Numpy/SciPy style docstring documentation? Is `object` the correct way to put it?

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        # Some data
    def create_B(self):
        new_B = B(self)  

class B:
    """
    This is the class for B
    ...
    
    Attributes
    ----------
    A : object
        Refers to the object of class A that created B
    """
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A
```

Comment: The type is `A`. Why were you thinking `object`? (Also, naming your variable and your attribute the same thing as the class, particularly in uppercase, is a bad idea.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah right, yep that makes sense, I was thinking object because I couldn't think of what built-in type to use. And agreed that my naming was bad practice in this class, I was just whipping up a quick example